# Is it possible to load styles from another vhost in same server?

Tags: php, vhosts

Is it possible to load css styles from another vhost on the same server?
For example I have two vhosts:
vhostA and vhostB... In my template file I set href attribute of my `<link>`-tag to the style
directory in vhostA.

Comment: It's irrelevant what VHost something is on. If it has a publicly accessible URL, then you can use that URL, from anywhere. It'll probably be a different domain than your primary domain, but you can still link to it perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It should be perfectly fine. Just remember to use the absolute URL of the stylesheet when linking to it in the HTML.